# how to add array to another array in Objective c, according to my following example?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Here is one code,

```
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [MagnetKeyValuePair keyValuePairWithKeyAndValue:@"test1" value:@"Q test"],
                           [MagnetKeyValuePair keyValuePairWithKeyAndValue:@"test2" value:@"W test"],
                           [MagnetKeyValuePair keyValuePairWithKeyAndValue:@"test3" value:@"E Test"],
                       nil];
```

so here, array is storing key and values.

I am using Library for Picker view. This is the link
https://github.com/ufukk/MagnetPopupPicker

[image]

So, I want to pass my own values which is in the form of id and name,

it can be NSArray and NSMutableArray

```
e.g NSMutableArray * name= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Aashu",@"Kaveri",@"Rutuja",nil];
    NSMutableArray * id= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
```

so I want to add to that another NSMutableArray. So, in uipickerview I see my friends name like following image.

[image]

The code is, for this image

```
self.button = [[MagnetPopupPickerButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 50, 150, 30)];
    self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    self.button.popoverColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.button setTitle:@"Select" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSArray *list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[MagnetKeyValuePair keyValuePairWithKeyAndValue:@"test1" value:@"Aashu"],
                     [MagnetKeyValuePair keyValuePairWithKeyAndValue:@"test2" value:@"Kaveri"],
                     [MagnetKeyValuePair keyValuePairWithKeyAndValue:@"test3" value:@"Rutuja"],
                     nil];

    [self.button setOptions:list keyNames:[MagnetKeyValuePair keyValuePairWithKeyAndValue:@"key" value:@"value"]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't use two arrays. This can easily lead to bugs. Use an array of dictionaries.
2. Use [`addObjectsFromArray`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1408963-addobjectsfromarray?language=objc).

Comment: Yea, you are right but, the code I am using that accept Array only. here is code,  [self.button setOptions:list keyNames:[MagnetKeyValuePair keyValuePairWithKeyAndValue:@"key" value:@"value"]];  In this code, setOptions is accepting NSArray.

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, so it should work out of the box. And you can always get an instance of `NSArray` from an instance of `NSMutableArray` by using `copy`.